# Managing textures in c# via instantiating them all in one or several arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, game-engine, sfml

I am developing a game in c#, I'm rather new at C#. I would like to know if this approach would affect adversely the performance?

> 1. Instantiate all textures in four categories, id est 4 different arrays.
> 2. This is to keep relevant textures apart from each other (example MonsterA needs 3 textures that are in the same array)
> 3. Have objects with generic Lists to point at the texture(s) they need.
> 4. Since the textures are in the same array this would help with the caching etc, I think

As far as I know List would only create pointers that have locality not so much the actual textures. I am Using SFML.Net, but this should apply to say, listing pictures of some sort, or listing objects you want to have locality.

The question is then, will doing this affect it adversely, will it work as I expect or will it not matter at all? And why?

Comment: Using `List<>` is fine. As regards performance, this depends on what you do with it. C# is fine for this. Unless you are developing a AAA title - I wouldn't worry too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are very serious about that - try all approaches and measure/compare. Don't forget to set your goals first, otherwise you'll be trying to save time/memory when it does not cause problem for your case. Note that you need to measure complete sequence you worry about, not just "load textures" part.

It is very unlikely if performance will be impacted by the way you are arranging metadata portion of textures (everything but image bytes) - the amount of memory used by images themselves would be much bigger than any list/dictionaries you refer textures from.

Main optimizations with textures are

- not load them at all till needed/potentially need
- somehow make them smaller (multiple detail levels, compression,...)
- sometimes number of textures matter and image strips / sprite sheets can be used to combine multiple images into one.

But for most projects doing nothing special is a good start - if you finished game/program that is somewhat slower that you'd like is much better than 1/3 complete one but with very fast texture loading (or whatever you decide to optimize too much).